# Encrypt data drive with USB key without encrypting the OS drive

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption

In my computer I have a SSD with an OS installed, and a HDD with two partitions, one of them I use to store my user profiles and other potentially sensitive data.

I would like to encrypt one of the data partitions, if possible without encrypting the OS disk, and I would like to have my key on a USB drive. When trying to use Bit-locker, I am offered to use the USB key only for my system drive, only password option is offered for the data drive. I assume if I encrypt the OS drive, I will be able to use the same key for the data drive (automatic unlock), however I would prefer not encrypting my OS drive, because I see no reason to lower its performance, as the OS drive does not contain any data I consider sensitive.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve this without command prompt or powershell.

Open a cmd window with admin rights (winkey + x)

For a new drive:

```
manage-bde -on D: -RecoveryKey F: -RecoveryPassword -UsedSpaceOnly
```

A RecoveryPassword (-rp) consisting of a long numerical code is displayed for you to copy to a safe place and to be used if you loose your USB key. 
The RecoveryKey (-rk) or StartupKey (-sk) puts an external key file on the USB drive F:. 
Add -UsedSpaceOnly to speed up encryption.

For an already encrypted drive:

```
Manage-bde D: -protectors -add -RecoveryKey F:
Manage-bde D: -protectors -add /?
```

The /? will result in a help overview.

After you have successfully added an external keyfile protector to the Data drive, Windows will not automatically unlock the Data drive when the USB key is detected. Bitlockers own autounlock-mechanism will add an external key file into the registry of Windows if you enable it, but this is only available if the system drive is encrypted. You cannot 'teach' windows to use the keyfile to autounlock the Data drive. You can add, however, a task in task scheduler, resulting in this behaviour.

```
manage-bde -unlock D: -RecoveryKey "F:\00000-...-.bek"
```

This time you do need to be specific in pointing to the file on the USB key (whereas saving the key to the USB-drive does not require you to be specific folder/filename).

**As stated in the comments below, you can also unlock the drive with the mouse using the blue links in the bitlocker-corner-popup.**

Comment: \ needs to be escaped as \\ - I cannot edit myselft as this is not 6 characters. :(

Comment: I have tried this and I am afraid it is not complete. The disk is not unlocked when I start the computer, I need to enter a long numeric password. When I check `Manage-bde X: -protectors -get`, the external key is listed as a file name only, with no path to the flash disk. I will try changing that with -protectors add.

Comment: I was not successful so far. Each attempt to use `Manage-bde D: -protectors -add -StartupKey "F:\\"` or `Manage-bde D: -protectors -add -RecoveryKey "F:\\"`creates a new key or recovery key on my USB stick, but the key is not used, the OS asks me for a password on first access.

Comment: Password will always take priority when it exists. If you use the GUI, click the blue sentence below the password box and then click the line "Load key from USB drive" ) it then will check for *.bek files in the root location of other (USB) drives. If you do not want the GUI to ask you for a password you will have to remove the password protector. The a clickable blue link will appear when you unlock the drive without a password box.

Comment: Still no luck. When I removed the password, the drive is still not unlocked on startup. When I click on the drive to open it, a window appears with an option "Load key from USB drive", but when I click it, an error shows: "A valid USB key wasn't detected". The BEK file is present on the USB, but somehow it is now found. As I have removed the recovery password protector before (it was the only password protector I had), I guess I have lost the drive. (This does not matter - it was just a testing drive, I expected something may go wrong).

Comment: Two things are happening here. 1. I expect after adding protectors and deleting them I think you might have deleted too many. You can always view them with `manage-bde D: -protectors -get`. - 2. Your expectations of the use case (steps with the software) do not match what the software can actually do. The GUI is limited compared to cmd/powershell. Please update your question with a step by step expectation and I will update my answer accordingly. Start with "- I turn on my computer." This will force you to be explicit on what you want.

Comment: I am quite sure I did not remove too many. The startup key was still present and listed as a protector, and it was referencing the correct key (the key ID on the USB matched the protector ID). Still both GUI and command line unlock was unable to find the key on the USB. After that I gave up and decided to rather encrypt the OS drive and bear the performance penalty (it will probably be not that bad anyway) rather than fighting with little used corners.

Comment: While searching now, I have found another user which tried to get this working. It worked on one computer for him and did not on another, . In his case the cause was USB device driver. See [Bitlocker problem](http://www.tenforums.com/antivirus-firewalls-system-security/28442-bitlocker-problem.html?s=5d345df0d853e9ed9cd584c1b019e04b). I am not sure if I will want to going through decryppting my OS again just to test if I can get it working too. :(